# How to resolve Spring Boot database error

Tags: java, spring-boot, mysql-connector

I received the following error when configuring Spring Boot to MySQL and running the application.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver

I am not using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version. I am using the IntelliJ IDEA Community version. I do see the IDE displaying the following error message in my application.properties file:

> Spring Boot Configurations are supported by IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Here is the configurations in my application.properties fileL

```ini
#configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JRPropertyManagement
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxxxx

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver
```

Could I have possibly configured something incorrectly, or could the issue be that I am not using the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version? If the issue is related to me not using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version, would Eclipse be a better IDE for Spring Boot Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123985/cannot-load-driver-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-spring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with IntellIJ ultimate, you can use any IDE of your choice.

The issue is the driver class name is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver and not com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver. Kindly note, Spring recommends not explicitly specifying the driver as it will register by itself

Hope this helps

Comment: For future reference, typos should be pointed out in the comments, and the question flagged/voted to close as caused by a typo.